# Using recursion tree to solve recurrence $T(n) = 3T(n/2)+n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am trying to solve the recurrence $T(n) = 3T(n/2)+n$ where $T(1) = 1$ and show its time complexity.

$n$ can be assumed to be a power of $2$.

---

So basically, I drew out the tree and found that:

the number of levels in the tree will be $h = \log_2 n+1$.

The number of leaves in the tree will then be $3^{h-1} = 3^{\log_2 (n) } = n^{\log_2 3}$

Now we can write the time formula..

$$T(n) = cn + c(3n/2) + c(9n/4) +\dots + cn(3^{h-2}/2(h-2)) + \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$$

[stuck here, how should I formulate the summation? The summation diverges at infinity..]

$$T(n) = \Theta (n^{\log_2 3})$$

I can tell that the summation of the number of leaves is $n$ times some constant but I am not sure how to show that step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our time formula is:
$$
T(n) = n + \frac{3}{2}n + \frac{3^2}{2^2}n + \cdots + \frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\log_2 n}}n
$$
[As an aside, note that the last term is just $n^{\log_2 3}$.] Now this is a finite geometric series with initial term $a = n$, common ratio $r = \frac{3}{2}$, and $N = \log_2 n + 1$ terms. [By applying the usual formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), we obtain:
\begin{align*}
T(n)
&= \frac{n((\frac{3}{2})^{\log_2 n + 1} - 1)}{\frac{3}{2} - 1} \\
&= \frac{n(3^{\log_2 n + 1} - 2^{\log_2 n + 1})}{3(2^{\log_2 n}) - 2^{\log_2 n + 1}} \\
&= \frac{n(3(3^{\log_2 n}) - 2(2^{\log_2 n}))}{3(2^{\log_2 n}) - 2(2^{\log_2 n})} \\
&= \frac{n(3(n^{\log_2 3}) - 2n)}{3n - 2n} \\
&= \frac{n(3n^{\log_2 3} - 2n)}{n} \\
&= 3n^{\log_2 3} - 2n \\
\end{align*}

which belongs to $\Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adriano! Very helpful. I was trying to solve the series with Wolfram, and it kept on giving me 'diverging'. I will keep that formula in my notes.

Comment: Oh - I also noticed that for the last term on the first line: `n*(3/2)^(log(2,n))`.. Shouldn't that be `n*(3^(log(2,n))/2*log(2,n)))`. I drew out the tree and it goes from `n/2` to `n/4` to `n/8` to `n/16`.

Comment: Hmm you'll have to explain what you mean. The denominator should be $2^{\log_2 n} = n$ (since a leaf node takes time $T(1) = 1$) and not $2 \cdot \log_2 n$. The running time of a child node is always half that of its parent; the denominator grows exponentially.

Comment: Oh right! I see that now; thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand the first step you take in the bottom listing - where do the log terms that show up in the denominator come from? Shouldn't the denominator simplify to just `1/2`? Edit: I see, you've decomposed the `(3/2)^x` to `(3^x)/(2^x)` and distributed and simplified exponents in the same step